# Darken screen when clicking on a link then redirect

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following [project](https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/lobby.html).

What I want is, when a user clicks on any link on the page, to slowly hide the image with the class `map` and smoothly display the black background, then return to its usual behaviour, redirecting the user to the next page.

My guess is that `preventDefault()` is the solution here together with some CSS like this one:

```
.hideImg{ 
 opacity: 0; 
 visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transition: visibility 0.3s linear,
 opacity 0.3s linear;
 -moz-transition: visibility 0.3s linear,
 opacity 0.3s linear;
 -o-transition: visibility 0.3s linear,
 opacity 0.3s linear; 
}

body{
background-color:#000;
}
```

However, I fail to make them work together and create a JS that waits for the hiding animation to occur and then redirect.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You did it from 0? Thats so cool.

Comment: You could use the transition end event:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend

Comment: @SilverSurfer Not really from 0, SO and Google haved been great allies . Thank you!

Comment: @Legends Yes, that seems to go in the right direction but unfortunately I have no idea how to apply this solution to my problem because I really suck at JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  
  // For one item
  $('.map').animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1000, function() {
    window.location.href = href;
  });
  
  // Or, for multiple classes - all doing the same thing
  $('.map, .another-item, .another-class').animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1000, function() {
    window.location.href = href;
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>

<div class='map' style="background: black; width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Comment: This works like a charm. If I want to hide two elements instead of one then I have to repeat this section $('.map').animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1000, function() { window.location.href = href; }); and change the class name, right?

Comment: Yes, if you want them to do different things. Alternatively - just use $('.map, .other-class')... (see updated answer.)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a class to the container that's holding the image.
And add an additional timeout before you go the new page.

```js
$(".x").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('div').addClass('darken');

  window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com'; // this will navigate to the new page after 2s
  }, 2000);

});
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.warpper-map {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

img.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.darken {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s ease; /* Makes smooth transition */
  /* You can increase the time to make the transition much longer */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='x' href="#">Click to Darken</a>
<div class='wrapper-map'>
  <img class='map' src="https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/images/Lobby.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the work for you using jQuery:

```
$('a').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    $(this).addClass('hideImage');
    $('.hideImage').on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd',function(){
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    })
});
```

or just give you the idea of how to fix it.
best of luck